# Unable to resolve dependency for custom buildType after update androidPlugin to 3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have multi module project with 3 `buildTypes`: release, debug, travis. All modules has Kotlin plugin. When I updated android plugin to `3.2.1`, I get error:

[image]

If I remove travis build type it works correctly.

If i remove kotlin-plugin from `core-utils` it works correctly.

What could be the problem?

Code `build.gradle` for `app` module:

```
buildTypes {
release {
  minifyEnabled true
  shrinkResources true

  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
debug {
  minifyEnabled false
  versionNameSuffix "-dev"
  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
travis {
  initWith debug
  minifyEnabled true
  shrinkResources true

  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

  matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
}
```

Code `build.gradle` for `core-utils` module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
    targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk
    versionCode=VERSION_CODE
    versionName=VERSION_NAME

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion for you to find the answer.comment you travis block and try to build again.if it was unsuccessful again go to your androidStudio setting > plugins then re-Enable kotlin plugin.it may work

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes. And it works if I remove one of the Fallbacks from `matchingFallbacks`. For example if I do so: `matchingFallbacks = ['release']` it works nice. But why?